# Div Swap with Timed Interval ensure pairing

Tags: javascript, html, hidden, timedelay

I've review some similar questions, but I can't seem to find an answer to tie this all together.  I am looking for a way to create a slideshow where images and a corrosponding block of text change every 10 seconds.    (Below, when I state Rotate, i do not mean turn on an angle, I mean change from one visible slide to another)

For further clarification, lets call one block of text and one image a "pair".  The block of text is contained in one  and the image is contained in another .  For this slideshow, I will have 10 pairs.

I can easily rotate an image inside  utilizing a simple time delay javascript, but if I utilize a similar javascript to rotate the text, sometimes the Image and Text get out of sync with each other (don't change at same time.)

So.... my question is a 2 part question.
1.) Am I approaching this in the correct way, and if so, how do I ensure the text and images stay as pairs and rotate at the same time.
2.) Instead of rotating the content inside of the same div, should I create 10 div pairs (20 total) and create a script just to make 2 of the 20 visible at the same time?  if so... any ideas on the script to do so?

Currently, I am using the following script to swap images:

```
<!--- Start Image Cycler Script --->
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
var timeDelay = 10; // change delay time in seconds
var Pix = new Array
("images2/slide_pics/92028.png" 
,"images2/slide_pics/92026.png" 
,"images2/slide_pics/92027.png" 
,"images2/slide_pics/92534.png" 
,"images2/slide_pics/92034.png" 
,"images2/slide_pics/92555.png" 
,"images2/slide_pics/92700.png" 
,"images2/slide_pics/A73495.png" 
,"images2/slide_pics/92701.png"  
);
var howMany = Pix.length;
timeDelay *= 1000;
var PicCurrentNum = 0;
var PicCurrent = new Image();
PicCurrent.src = Pix[PicCurrentNum];
function startPix() {
setInterval("slideshow()", timeDelay);
}
function slideshow() {
PicCurrentNum++;
if (PicCurrentNum == howMany) {
PicCurrentNum = 0;
}
PicCurrent.src = Pix[PicCurrentNum];
document["ChangingPix"].src = PicCurrent.src;
}
//  End -->
</script>
<!--- End Image cycler Script --->

        <img name="ChangingPix" src="images2/slide_pics/92028.png" alt="" width="570" height="346"  class="head-pic" />
```

Comment: BTW, we haven't needed to hide blocks of javascript <!-- Begin ... //  End --> since 1997.

Comment: yes, i realize you don't have to hide anymore.  I still hide during my construction phase of a page for internal markup notes to myself.  This way, it's simple to swap out lines of code and easily find items.  It's just a system that seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry, my last comment decided to post itself)

As Kevin Nelson suggested, I would simply put the image and text in the same containing "block".

```
<div id="slider">


    <div class="slide">
    <img src="#" alt"this is the image" />
    <p>This is the description for this particular slide</p>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
    <img src="#" alt"this is the image" />
    <p>This is the description for this particular slide</p>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
    <img src="#" alt"this is the image" />
    <p>This is the description for this particular slide</p>
    </div>

    </div>
```

That way you do not run into any issues with the text and images getting out of sync. There are plenty of free content/image sliders out there. I have been using [**Slides.js**](http://slidesjs.com/) for client work as of late. It is really easy to set up and customize to your liking. It also has plenty of options (e.g. pause on hover, auto play).

Comment: I see what you're trying to do, but the items that need to rotate at the same time are in two separate <div>s on different parts of page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but if you want to rotate text and images at same time, why wouldn't you create blocks and rotate the entire block.  See this page:

http://rhmachine.flashfirehosting.com/

If I'm understanding the question correctly and you want something like that, let me know and I'll post the jquery plugin that I'm using to do it.